# School Wifi? Installing CA-CERTIFICATES

Tags: networking, 20.04

My school has several CA-CERTIFICATES. But they do not support Linux for school wifi which is a problem for me, because I am very heavily involved with CMake OpenCV Cuda. They have however told me to manually install the CA-CERTIFICATES to do this I have followed these steps:

1. Go to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`
2. Create a new folder, i.e. `sudo mkdir school`
3. Copy the `.crt` file into the school folder
4. Make sure the permissions are OK (755 for the folder, 644 for the file) #I did this through `chmod`
5. Run `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

However when I wrote `sudo update-ca-certificates` it said 0 removed and 0 added. (I did put it in the correct path /usr/local/share/ca-certficates). Also it did not connect to school wifi after those steps.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to do this *before* you run that last command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`.

Comment: Were you able to fix it ?